# Производительность запроса с подзапросом

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть запрос следующего вида

```
select t1.filed1, t2.filed2
from t1
inner join t2 on ...
where t1.id = ...
and exist(select 1 
            from t3
            where t3.id = t1.other_id and t3.enabled)
```

мой внтуренний голос подсказывает перепиши это на

```
select t1.filed1, t2.filed2
from t1
inner join t2 on ...
inner join t3 on ...
where t1.id = ...
and t3.enabled
```

но нет понятия что именно происходит под капотом, как строится/ выполняется запрос в обоих случаях и почему один из них быстрее, смотрел планы но ничего вразумительного для себя не открыл

может кто объяснить какая механика происходит "подкапотом" каждого из запросов

Comment: а зачем вы условия джойна переносите в where ?

Comment: @teran вы о втором варианте? если да, то там мог бы быть и left join и как по мне то `t3.enabled`  то это не условие джоина а условие ограничения выборки

Comment: первый запрос, это уменьшеный псевдозапрос реального запроса, и вопрос наверное будет в том какая разница между джоином таблицы и использованием подзапроса в where

Comment: Что будет "под капотом" зависит от того, какие планы выберет постргрес. Если запросы по сути эквивалентны, то и планы могут быть абсолютно одинаковыми, а могут быть и разные планы. Нужно смотреть именно на планы. Даже один и тот же запрос на разных данных (или с разной собранной статистикой на тех же данных) будет выполняться по разному. По плану обычно можно сказать, насколько хорошо он будет себя вести при увеличении количества данных (и правильно собранной статистике) и тем более можно сравнить какой лучше. Ну а на вопрос в текущем виде нельзя дать однозначный ответ - нужны планы запросов.

Comment: @JVic джйоном вы делаете декартово произведение таблиц. Можете перемножить много данных и потом фильтровать этот большой объекм, а можете изначально задав все условия джойна перемножить мало данных без потребности в фильтрации. Чем больше джйонов будет, тем все больше будет увеличиваться объем выборки перед фильтрацией.

Comment: @teran согласен, что с точки зрения поддерживаемости и прозрачности кода условие джойна нужно писать в `on`. Но то что вы написали про декартово произведение, фильтрацию и производительность для постгреса неверно в общем случае. Планировщик постгреса понимает, что даже если условие в where, то его можно (и если это ускорит запрос то имеет смысл) использовать для фильтрации до (или во время) джойна. И генерирует правильный план (а не сначала все объединяет, а потом фильтрует как вы пишете). Если речь конечно идет о идентичных по смыслу запросах, ведь иногда перенос условия меняет смысл запроса.

Comment: @RomanKonoval я понимаю, что мб в большинстве случаев будет разрулено автоматически. Но подозреваю, что это не всегда так так. Тут в целом полно вопросов, например, про оптимизацию SQL server, где вынесение условий в джойн кратно увеличивает производительность. Так что, пусть и не с точки зрения производительности, но понятности кода писать условия лучше в само джойне а не создавать солянку в where

Comment: Кажеться дело в том, что `join` как фундамент RDBMS оптимизировался 40+ лет лучьшим людям в DB мире, а то же самое с подзапросами - не очень, так как сделать ето намного сложнее и каждий случай разний. Простите если написано с ошибками :)